# Changing the text of a label when a collection view cell is tapped in swift 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am having a problem with changing the text of a label when a collection view cell is tapped. I have tried using `didSelectItemAt` and `didHighlightItemAt` but nothing worked. Here's what my cell looks like:

[image: Cell]

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.subjectName.text = "Selected"
}
```

Comment: **Never ever** use `dequeueReusableCell` outside of `cellForRow/Item`. It cannot work. Where do you hand over the dequeued cell  to the table/collection view? And every manipulation of the cell in `didSelect` is not persistent. Keep the **model** and the **view** in sync and get the data from the **model**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
let cell = collectionview.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
cell.subjectName.text = "Selected"
```

but note because of cell dequeuing this change is temporary when the cell is still shown if you scroll around you may find another text inside that index , so reflect the changes in the array model of the collection and reload that indexPath

```
var statesArr = ["Selected","Default",,,,,,,,,,]
```

inside `didSelectItemAt`

```
statesArr[indexPath.row] = "Selected"
self.collectionView.reloadItems(at:[indexPath])
```

inside `cellForItemAt`

```
let cell = ///
cell.subjectName.text = statesArr[indexPath.row]
```